# Customizing deploy key and ssh wrapper path for git cloning through application_git cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, devops, chef-recipe, chef-custom-resource

I am using chef for managing servers. Earlier I was using application cookbook for cloning repository. But now in higher version of application cookbook, this support is moved to new cookbook application_git.
I am using 1.1.0

Issue -

1. I want to change the path of deploy key
2. Contents of ssh_wrapper
3. Path of ssh_wrapper.

What all I have tried - 
Current code -

```
application 'accounts' do
  action :deploy
  path <somepath>
  owner 'nobody'
  group 'nogroup'
  git 'name' do
    repository <repopath>
    revision <value>
    deploy_key deploy_key
 end
end
```

I am not able to find if I need to pass path using ssh_wrapper_path or ssh_wrapper or deploy_key_path. All are failing.

Currently, I am able to get keys and wrapper but at a wrong place.

Comment: What is your end goal? You cannot modify any of those things with app_git (or poise-git which it is built on).

Comment: I need to download deploy_key at a particular location, otherwise, my servers won`t work.

Comment: Then don't use app_git. You'll have to handle writing it yourself, usually with a `file` resource or similar. app_git's deploy key handling is only for the purposes of Chef's git operations, if your app itself needs to also touch git, then you need to do that yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Copied from comments:

Then don't use app_git. You'll have to handle writing it yourself, usually with a `file` resource or similar. app_git's deploy key handling is only for the purposes of Chef's git operations, if your app itself needs to also touch git, then you need to do that yourself :)